# the phone didn’t go in Doze (sleep) Mode when using Alarm Manager every 5 seconds

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I used Alarm Manager to trigger every 5 seconds and it works fine. But the problem is the phone didn't go into sleep mode and I can't see the gap from the collected data using alarm manager. 
Can anyone help me how to check if the phone goes into sleep correctly or not?

here is my code

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
public void startAlarm() {
manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int interval = 5000;
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `AlarmManager` you ensure that your app will be waken by the system even if the phone is sleep and your activity/service is in the background.
But this does **not** mean your app (or any other app) have the ability to force the device into [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

In order to validate that your app works in Doze as expected use this command to force the device into Doze mode:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

**Additional Info**
this method:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP...
```

**WILL NOT** wakeup the device if it's in Doze mode, only after the device will get out from the Doze mode.
To ensure your app will work in Doze use this command:

```
 alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, But how can I do to ensure whether my app is waken  by the system or not?  Because from my collected data I can't see any gap. It seems always collecting data every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Hiwot ,I edited the answer to fully answer your question.